# Gerund usage: when can verbs be used as -ing nouns?

Tags: verbs, nouns, gerunds, subjects

I have a question regarding the correct usage of verbs as nouns ending in -ing (I understand that these are referred to as gerunds). Under what circumstance may a gerund be used in place of the verb it is derived from? In particular, *is it acceptable for a gerund to be the subject of a sentence?* Consider these examples:

1) Analyzing data is difficult.

2) The analysis of data is difficult.

Which of the above examples are correct? If both are correct, is one example preferred over the other?

Comment: Both are correct.  Preference for one over the other would be on the basis of style and/or context.

Answer (score 2):

A verb plus -ing form used in a nominalized sentence is a gerund.  It's a verb. A nominalized sentence is a sentence given a form that lets it occupy the position of a NP, e.g. subject, direct object, object of a preposition.  So, yes, subject position is okay.

A gerund is not a noun.  It's a verb which, like other verbs, can take a direct object (provided the verb is transitive), can be modified by an adverb (but not an adjective), does not take an article.

Confusingly, there are also nominalized sentences with nouns that have been derived from verbs.  The term for these is *derived nominal*.  Your example "the analysis of data" is a derived nominal.  "Analysis" here is a noun, not a verb.  Notice that like other common nouns, and unlike verbs, it does take an article, but does not take a direct object (the logical object "data" has to be expressed as a prepositional phrase, because it can't be made a direct object).

Even more confusingly, there are -ing nouns derived from verbs that occur in nominalizations.  For your examples, we could also get "The analyzing of data is difficult."  Here, like "analysis", "analyzing" is a noun.

There are sometimes meaning differences between nominalizations with -ing, which can refer to facts, and nominalizations with derived nominals, which can refer to actions or the manner of some event or process.

Ronald Langacker gives an able and concise summary of the classical analysis of the two kinds of nominalizations [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=o5yDpuZL3iEC&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=factive%20nominalization&source=bl&ots=WZOX9kIgJT&sig=qIXbt93ioCEZd5jO_45AjSzIL6c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f4VCVYncC8jmoATR6oHQAw&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=factive%20nominalization&f=false).  McCawley adds some interesting analytic details (as usual) in **The Syntactic Phenomena of English**.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer. Regarding the examples given, is (1) grammatically correct?

Comment: Both your examples are grammatical and sound fine to me.  I don't know about "correct".  As @phoog remarked in a comment, there might be stylistic reasons to prefer one over the other.  (The 3rd version, which I gave, "The analyzing of data is difficult", sounds awkward, to me.)

Comment: Yeah, generally a derived event noun like _analyzing_ would not be likely if there were already a differently derived event noun from the same root like _analysis_. By the way, there are a number of constructions involving _-ing_ forms of verbs; only one of them is a gerund. http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html

Comment: A 'gerund' is a verb rather than a noun according to the opinions of some. Aarts looks at the alternative approaches (dual membership and gradience).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, yes, a gerund is a verb, according to my opinion also.  That's what I said in my answer.

Comment: Let me repeat. A 'gerund' is a verb rather than a noun according to the opinions of _some_. I'm saying that Aarts describes schools treating the _ing_-form in 'Analyzing data is difficult.' as (a) something neither a noun nor a verb but somewhere in between; (b) more x than y, so we'll call it an x; (c) both a noun and a verb at the same time [Aarts & McMahon, _English Word Classes and Phrases; 2.3 Word Class Boundaries and Gradience_] [where linguists in the various camps are mentioned]. You give one opinion and make it sound like a done deal.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, it is a done deal, wanting evidence to the contrary.  I gave evidence.  I don't see why I should be concerned because there is *opinion* to the contrary.  People have all sorts of strange ideas.  Why should anyone care what these other "schools" think?  Do they have evidence?  If not, they don't count.  If there is evidence for such other views, it seems to me it's up to you to tell us what it is, or at least give a reference to where we can find it.

Comment: Again? (This has all been covered before.) And what's wrong with the Aarts / McMahon reference, and their references to the different schools?

Comment: Yes, I've covered it in previous answers.  I haven't read your Aarts / McMahon reference.  Should I?  If you're recommending it, it's up to you to tell us why.  What's the evidence?  We're not back in the middle ages, are we?, when such discussions involved only appeals to various authorities.

Comment: Let's be friends, guys :)